# Angular dropmenu issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to pass information from the drop menu into a var and don't know the next step.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1azq9qvj/3/)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

var nextVXPLevelValue = 260;
var currentLevel = 10;

var VXP = [2.41, 2.50, 1.80, 1.56, 1.43, 1.35, 1.30, 1.26, 1.23, 1.20, 1.1, 1.17, 1.16, 1.14, 1.13, 1.13, 1.12, 1.11, 1.11, 1.10, 1.10, 1.09, 1.09, 1.08, 1.08];
var i;
var vxpResult = [];
var iResult = [];

for (i = 0 + (currentLevel + 1); i < VXP.length; i++) {
    nextVXPLevelValue *= VXP[i];
    vxpResult.push(Math.floor(nextVXPLevelValue));
    iResult.push(i + 1);
}


function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.level = iResult;
    $scope.vxp = vxpResult;
}

function TheController($scope) {

    $scope.Levels = [
        {LevelId : 50, LevelName : '--Select Level--'}, 
        {LevelId : 0, LevelName : 'Level 0' },        
        {LevelId : 1, LevelName : 'Level 1' },
        {LevelId : 2, LevelName : 'Level 2' },
        {LevelId : 3, LevelName : 'Level 3' },        
        {LevelId : 4, LevelName : 'Level 4' },
        {LevelId : 5, LevelName : 'Level 5' }, 
        {LevelId : 6, LevelName : 'Level 6' },
        {LevelId : 7, LevelName : 'Level 7' },
        {LevelId : 8, LevelName : 'Level 8' },        
        {LevelId : 9, LevelName : 'Level 9' },
        {LevelId : 10, LevelName : 'Level 10' },
        {LevelId : 11, LevelName : 'Level 11' },
        {LevelId : 12, LevelName : 'Level 12' },
        {LevelId : 13, LevelName : 'Level 13' },        
        {LevelId : 14, LevelName : 'Level 14' },
        {LevelId : 15, LevelName : 'Level 15' }, 
        {LevelId : 16, LevelName : 'Level 16' },
        {LevelId : 17, LevelName : 'Level 17' },
        {LevelId : 18, LevelName : 'Level 18' },        
        {LevelId : 19, LevelName : 'Level 19' },
        {LevelId : 20, LevelName : 'Level 20' },  
        {LevelId : 21, LevelName : 'Level 21' },
        {LevelId : 22, LevelName : 'Level 22' },
        {LevelId : 23, LevelName : 'Level 23' },        
        {LevelId : 24, LevelName : 'Level 24' },
        {LevelId : 25, LevelName : 'Level 25' },
  ];

    $scope.LevelId =50;

}
```

This is as far as i got, but i want to now change the manual

> var currentLevel = 10;

to be the result of the drop menu that i have. could someone help with this please

Answer (score 1):

Example code:  http://jsfiddle.net/024ucmtL/1/

Move your code all into one controller.  Then expose currentLevel to your $scope 
`$scope.currentLevel = 10`

You can then bind your select element's ng-model to currentLevel, and use a $watch on $scope.currentLevel to watch for it to change.  Process and update your $scope.vxp any time $scope.currentLevel changes.

```
$scope.$watch('currentLevel', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  // your vxp calculations here.  This code should set $scope.vxp at the end.
});
```

Comment: i want to get rid of the static "10" and make it equal whatever is selected from the drop menu

Comment: Binding your select element's ng-model to currentLevel will accomplish that part ;)

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide an example jsfiddle

Comment: Thank you Travis, that is what i am going for, but i notice the VXP column has some issues with it now... I will relook at it.. i.e, if i changed to level 11 then back to level 10 it goes wrong. i am going to add another drop menu for the initial VXP for that level

Comment: I can't vote till I get 15 rep points. I am at work and haven't got access to my fb login due to work restriction so had to create this account to ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-change` to know whenever the dropdown value is changed and manually update the `currentLevel` non scope variable inside it.
[See the updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/divm/unajrv9d/1/).